# Custom class FileInputFormat on hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I am running the WordCount example on hadoop and I want to read the whole content of the file. I used the examples from [here](https://gist.github.com/sritchie/808035) (WholeFileInputFormat-NewAPI.java and WholeFileRecordReader-NewAPI.java). I added in my WordCount class this: conf.setInputFormat(WholeFileInputFormat.class);

When I compile the program I get thee following error:

```
 error: method setInputFormat in class JobConf cannot be applied to given types;
        conf.setInputFormat(WholeFileInputFormat.class);
            ^
  required: Class<? extends InputFormat>
  found: Class<WholeFileInputFormat>
  reason: argument mismatch; Class<WholeFileInputFormat> cannot be converted to Class<?   extends InputFormat>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As the API says, `setInputFormat` expects a type which extends `InputFormat`. `WholeFileInputFormat` doesn't qualify, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using old APIs while `WholeFileInputFormat` is of new API. You should use new API too.

Comment: In `JobConfig.setInputFormat(Class<? extends InputFormat> theClass)`, the Class should extend **`org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InutFormat`** (old [API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html#setInputFormat(java.lang.Class))), but `WholeFileInputFormat` extends **`org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat`** (new API).